# Clock in Windows Vista (Ultimate Edition) is always 10 minutes fast

Tags: windows-vista, clock

I have an annoying problem on my main pc (Thinkpad T61 running Windows Vista Ultimate edition). The clock (displayed in the lower right taskbar area) seems to be always 10 minutes fast. I have edited my time zone information more than once to make sure it is correct, changed the time manually using the UI to be the correct time, only to discover at some point in the future that the clock is again 10 minutes fast. (The time resets while the computer is running, not upon just upon system start up).

What's more annoying, I can't edit the NTP Server info (through the UI at least) as that tab is not visible in Vista Ultimate.

Anyone have the same problem, or know of a way to fix this permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the computer on a domain? If so, it is inheriting the NTP parameters of the domain controller (which is apparently 10 minutes fast). Contact your system administrator.

The tab to change NTP servers is visible in Ultimate if you are not on a domain and your polices do not prevent you from modifying the NTP information.

Comment: Thanks, I should have checked that long ago. I never noticed that the Domain Controller was also 10 minutes fast.

Comment: I'd highly recommend setting up some kind of synchronization service for you domain controller.  Whether it's using NTP or a GPS unit, keeping the time correct on the DC is quite important.

Comment: @Russ: Agreed. Your country usually provided a Stratum 1 NTP server of their respective atomic clock. That would be a good place to start. For example, Canada's server address is time.chu.nrc.ca.